# My username not displaying in Favorites on the left

Tags: macos, finder, sidebar

I have a setting that whenever I open up Finder, it would open my username files.

However, it does not show within Favorites. Why does it not show there? How can I add my username there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finder → Preferences (⌘,) → Sidebar and enable the option for your home folder.

[image]

It's enabled by default, so perhaps you removed it accidentally, either by dragging it off the window or right-clicking and choosing Remove from Sidebar?